# How to plot sine curve in Latex

Tags: latex

I have these curves that I'd like to express in Latex, I am new to Latex so I'm not sure how it could be done. I tried to follow a guide myself that looked similar but I don't know how to make it just like mine.

```
\begin {document}
\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
minor tick num=3,
axis y line=left,
axis x line=middle,
xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$\sin x$,
yticklabels=\empty,
ymax=2,
ymin=-2,
]
\addplot[smooth,blue,mark=none,
domain=0:10,samples=40]
{cos(deg(2*x))};
\end{axis}
\begin{axis}[
minor tick num=3,
xticklabels=\empty,
yticklabels=\empty,
axis y line=left,
axis x line=middle,
xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$\sin x$,
ymax=2,
ymin=-2,
]
\addplot[smooth,blue,mark=none,dashed,
domain=0:10,samples=40]
{cos(deg(3*x))};
\end{axis}


\begin{axis}[
minor tick num=3,
xticklabels=\empty,
yticklabels=\empty,
ymax=1,
ymin=-1,
axis y line=left,
axis x line=middle,
xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$\sin x$,
yticklabels={,-2},
]
\addplot[smooth,blue,mark=none,dotted,
domain=0:10,samples=40]
{sin(deg(x))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The graph that I followed looked like this:

[image]

The graph that I want to be written into Latex:

[image]

Comment: have a look at pgfplots

Comment: Yea ive seen it but i dont know how i would express these curves...

Comment: If you would make a [mre] that shows how far you got by yourself (hint: there are a lot of example in the user guide), I'm sure we can help you with the rest

Answer (score 2):

- to add a black background, you can use the trick from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/101610/36296
- to get external axis like in your picture, remove the `axis ... line` instructions from your code
- change the colours to your taste

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
% background color definition from pgfmanual-en-macros.tex
\definecolor{graphicbackground}{rgb}{0.96,0.96,0.8}
% key to change color
\pgfkeys{/tikz/.cd,
  background color/.initial=graphicbackground,
  background color/.get=\backcol,
  background color/.store in=\backcol,
}
\tikzset{background rectangle/.style={
    fill=\backcol,
  },
  use background/.style={    
    show background rectangle
  }
}

\begin{document}
\noindent

\begin{tikzpicture}[background color=black,use background]
\color{white}
\begin{axis}[
  minor tick num=3,
%  axis y line=left,
%  axis x line=bottom,
  xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$\sin x$,
%  yticklabels=\empty,
  ymax=2,
  ymin=-2,
  background/.style={fill=gray},
]
\addplot[smooth,blue,mark=none, domain=0:10,samples=40]
{cos(deg(2*x))};
\addplot[smooth,red,mark=none, domain=0:10,samples=40]
{cos(deg(3*x))};
\addplot[smooth,green,mark=none,domain=0:10,samples=40]
{2*sin(deg(x))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]